# Android, iphone-like back button in header as part of layout

Tags: android, ios, user-experience, back, emulation

I frequently get designs for android apps featuring iphone-like functionality. In this case it has to do with a back button integrated in the layout as part of the header (on the left side).

Android already comes with a back button - although I have seen some technophobes completely ignore the back button and complain about the flow of an app. ("why is their no cancel button, 1 star, uninstall" push back)

First of all, recreating iOS elements is tedious and counterproductive, but in this case do android users expect a back button in the header at this point? Would a "back" button subtract from a UX at all?

For instance, Android users expect to long-click items in a listview to see what happens - often for options or to delete. Or at least the assumption can be made.

But for a back button in the layout, do Android users get enough apps with iOS-style back buttons to simply expect it?

Insight appreciated

Comment: I am also currently around this type of thing. Firstly there is always a back key in android phones so there is no need for back button in android phones.Since iphone doesn't have back button so they implemented in the layout as navigation bar. There is no such thing like navigation in android. In android if you want to implement the back button then u need to add a top linear layout in each design layout which contains the back button in it.

Comment: Maneesh thank you, I know this, but I am wondering about if it adds or subtracts to the android user experience

Comment: you can't expect everything copy from IOS to android. Every Os has there unique feature. From my side back button in the Android will work same as back button on the screen of iPhone handling stack activity concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing a back button taking up screen real estate really has no point or benefit for an Android user. The only thing it does is cramp the UI for no real reason since the back button already exists.

Android users don't expect a software back button, since it's simply not the Android way of going back and not many apps have it.. hardly any apps have it actually.

Not only is a software back button completely unnecessary but it could even irritate the user   since it could be seen as trying to "iPhone-ify" the app. Not popular at all for some Android users ;)

Comment: now the problem with this logic - although amongst developers what you said is a common consensus - is that during QA and live I encounter a lot of older users and technophobes, and these Android users do not know the back button. Also, the back button is in different places on android phones, I'm finding it less and less convincing that Android users actually find that intuitive as part of the UX

Comment: If they don't know the existance of the back button I doubt they would be able to have navigated themselfs in Android for more than about minute :) That the back button is placed differently on Android phones is not really an argument since the user is used to where the back button is placed on his/her OWN phone. I use alot of apps and I can't think of a single one that actually has a back button on screen. So if there are practically almost no apps that use it, then how can Android-users not understand the back button since it is the only way to go back in the vast majority of the apps?

Comment: I don't know how technophobes think. I just have been on several projects that have involved a crowd that wasn't the trendiest. I've repeated myself many times to designers and clients about how android users should just "get" the back button, but when you look at your parents and their friends try to use their android phone, it isn't intuitive. But I've also found those people to not use "apps" or even know what they are. In that case, using the home button to get out of an app is probably most used